# How to separate IDs into different rows using R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I am using R. I have a column in a dataframe. Here is an example of part of the column:

```
|NEW.ID|
|------|
|P02538 [551-559]; P04259 [551-559]|
|A0A0B4J2F2 1xPhospho [T473]|
|Q8IVF2 1xPhospho [S1253]; 1xPhospho [S1748]|
|A0A1B0GX95 2xPhospho [S24; S26]|
```

I want to separate the rows where there are two accession code IDs. Although the IDs are separated by ';' , I need to take into account that some IDs may have a ';' in it such as the third row in the column above. The only way I can see to distinguish the separation if I have a condition that states if it has '];' followed by a letter, split the row. However, I don't know how to go about this.

So in the example column above, I want to achieve:

```
|NEW.ID|
|------|
|P02538 [551-559]|
|P04259 [551-559]|
|A0A0B4J2F2 1xPhospho [T473]|
|Q8IVF2 1xPhospho [S1253]; 1xPhospho [S1748]|
|A0A1B0GX95 2xPhospho [S24; S26]|
```

So the original first row is split into two.
Any help would be much appreciated and please say if further clarification is required (I am still relatively new to stackoverflow).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you share your dataframe using `dput`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to go about it and I don't feel comfortable sharing the whole dataframe due to research data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `separate_rows` with a regex lookaround - i.e. split at the `;` followed by a space ( ) that succeeds a closing bracket (`]`) and before an upper case letter

```
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df1, NEW.ID, sep = "(?<=\\]); (?=[A-Z])")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 1
  NEW.ID                                     
  <chr>                                      
1 P02538 [551-559]                           
2 P04259 [551-559]                           
3 A0A0B4J2F2 1xPhospho [T473]                
4 Q8IVF2 1xPhospho [S1253]; 1xPhospho [S1748]
5 A0A1B0GX95 2xPhospho [S24; S26]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(NEW.ID = c("P02538 [551-559]; P04259 [551-559]", 
"A0A0B4J2F2 1xPhospho [T473]", "Q8IVF2 1xPhospho [S1253]; 1xPhospho [S1748]", 
"A0A1B0GX95 2xPhospho [S24; S26]")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: No this doesn't work as for some IDs there is a ; in the middle e.g row 4 in example (A0A1B0GX95 2xPhospho [S24; S26])

Comment: @Rachel if the example is as you showed and the expected is only splitting the first row,  my solution is getting the expected output as showed.  Can you test using the data in my post

Comment: Oh sorry realised that you updated your answer, originally it just said sep = ";". It works now- thank you so much! I will upvote this answer.

Comment: @Rachel i had a typo earlier, I used `[` instead of `]`

Comment: Realised I can't upvote. I want to tick it but it won't let me at the moment. Will try again later.

Comment: Ah yes, it works now. Thank you once again.